# Testing UI updates caused by state changes

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I'm having a `create-react-app` and am trying to test a functional component. The component makes a service call on initial mount and sets the state and populates a material ui `select` based on the results.

Now, the user can pick one of those options on the select and I make another service call to retrieve more data based on that.

I am able to mock the initial service call, return mock values and prove that the `select` got populated but I am having trouble with finding the mocked option text in the select. I get an error - Unable to find an element with the text. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements.

Here is how my test looks like:

```
const fetchMock = jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch').mockImplementation(() => 
Promise.resolve({ ok: true, json: () => Promise.resolve([{itemName: 
'Color', itemId: 23},
 {itemName: 'Car', itemId: 34}])}));

 const localhostURL = "http://localhost:8080";
 let retrieveByLabelTextFunction;
 let retrieveByRole;
 act(() => { const { getByLabelText } = 
 render(<ItemSelection/>);
 retrieveByLabelTextFunction = getByLabelText;
 retrieveByRole = getByRole;
  });
 expect(fetchMock).toBeCalledWith(localhostURL + '/items/');
 findByDisplayValue("Color");
 findByDisplayValue("Car");
   
  const items = retrieveByLabelTextFunction("Items");
  fireEvent.mouseDown(items);
  const itemListbox = within(retrieveByRole("listbox"));
  fireEvent.click(itemListbox.getByText("I34 - Car"));
```

Any thoughts on how to test this scenario? `I34` in the text is added by the code under test appending the id basically.

Comment: What does the DOM look like during the test after the select has been populated? You can use [`debug` function](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#debug) from `react-testing-library` to check it.

Comment: @juliomalves I don't see any values in any of the dynamic dropdowns after looking at the output. I can see selected values for the statically populated dropdowns.